# como usar o LDAP_BIND no php utilizando NTLM2?

Tags: php, login

estou utilizando ldap com NTLM para fazer SSO "LOGON UNICO" porem estou tendo uma dificuldade,
o LDAP_BIND não aceita a senha em hash que eu recebo do navegador,

minha classe que trabalha com NTLM tem as seguintes variáveis:

```
$auth = getAuth(); //RETORNA O NTLM TRABALHADO

        //$auth['user'] = $user;
        //$auth['domain'] = $domain;
        //$auth['workstation'] = $workstation;
        //$auth['clientblob'] = $clientblob;
        //$auth['clientblobhash'] = $clientblobhash;

          $con = ldap_connect('meudominio.com');
          ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
          ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
          ldap_bind($con, 'dominio\user', $auth['clientblob']);
```

ERRO> Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in...
Obs: o LDAP_BIND funciona somente se eu usar a senha em string;

Comment: A senha que você passa para o `ldap_bind` tem que ser em plain text. Pelo menos todos os locais que implementei este tipo de autenticação, tive que fazer em plain text.

Comment: A senha que o NTLM envia não esta em texto plano...
O ntlm que criptografa a senha ? ou ele envia a senha já criptografada ? estou com essa dúvida tb.
Se for criptografada pelo NTLM2 como descriptografar ?
Desde ja agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo sua pergunta nos comentários, que é mais simples: NTML não é um protocolo de criptografia, e sem um protocolo de autenticação baseado em challenge-response que faz uso de funções de hash para "ocultar" a senha e então trafegá-la.

Não é possível utilizar LDAP+NTLM em PHP diretamente através do `mod_ldap`, pois ele foi feito para seguir rigorosamente o protocolo LDAP. Utilizar NTLM sobre LDAP, tal qual a Microsoft faz, é uma extensão à funcionalidade tradicional do LDAP. Com certeza ele pode ser implementado, mas é necessário fazer engenharia reversa dos parâmetros utilizados pela Microsoft, uma vez que estes não são documentados.

A API da Microsoft responsável por fazer isso no Windows, é a `ldap_bind_s` [[1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cellfish/ntlm-php)].

Uma opção que não envolve todo esse esforço, é utilizar o `mod_auth_ntlm_winbind`, que implementa este tipo de autenticação. Talvez utilizando Kerberos `mod_auth_kerb` também seja possível, mas não sei ao certo. Mas, se você deseja apenas pegar o nome de usuário logado na máquina acessando seu site, este [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cellfish/ntlm-php) provavelmente irá resolver o seu problema.

Em todo caso, recomendo que não "confie" no usuário/domínio enviado para você pelo browser: não é nem um pouco difícil forjar esta informação, especialmente se o sistema for acessado de fora da sua intranet. Para isto, recomendo que use LDAP + SSL (ou TLS), que apesar de exigir usuário e senha, trafegam as informações criptografadas e é de fácil implementação (`mod_ldap` já possui implementado). E não se esqueça de usar HTTPS na sua página de autenticação!